# What package does taskwarrior use to generate the tables on the command line?

Tags: python, command-line-interface, taskwarrior

I was wondering if taskwarrior uses any open-source packages to generate its output or have they written it completely from scratch? I would like to generate CLI output in a similar format, i.e. colored text, properly formatted tables, and different formatting all on the same table.

Comment: AFAIK Taskwarrior is implemented in C++, can't see how you could easily reuse its components in Python.  But I may be wrong.

Comment: You can check their [GitHub](https://github.com/robgolding/tasklib) if you want to see how they do it, but it's written in C++ as @gboffi mentioned.